# What (standard) protocols offer piecemeal access to streams?

Tags: web-services, rest, web-applications, streaming, protocols

I have an application in which I need to access large files remotely in a piecemeal fashion.  I will know the start offset, but - having read some prefix of the file from that position onwards, I will establish another new offset, and will want to read next from this new position - crucially - having suffered the minimum possible latency.

I've considered using HTTP - posting a request detailing the offset at which to start a transfer - but I don't want to either specify a transfer size (a size too small would lead to low throughput; a size too large would lead to an unacceptable latency.) or drop an open connection - as that incurs a latency penalty on reconnection.

I've considered 'rolling my own' with TCP/UDP and sockets - but it feels as if this approach involves re-inventing the wheel.  UDP might promise lowest latency, but I am not in a position to trade reliability for lower-latency.

I would be very interested to be pointed towards any standards (proposals, RFCs - etc.) about protocols to tackle this mode of access to data.  Perhaps there's a good approach developed already in the context of cloud storage?

Comment: search the web for "udp reliable data transfer", you'll find some interesting points like UDT.

Comment: @Ron Klein: I'm aware that there are various ways to make UDP reliable - and that, in some circumstances, this will outperform TCP.  My hunch, however, is that TCP, rather than UDP, based protocols will best suit my needs... because, while I sometimes jump to new positions in the file, having done so, I'll be streaming from that offset.  UDT and the like don't seem ideal as I really want to adopt a higher-level protocol - one that supports streaming and repositioning... and not much else.

Answer (score 0):

What you want, I believe, is a variation of the FTP protocol (RFC 959: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc959). I don't think there's any established protocol standard for what you want to do, exactly, but FTP is very close. It uses two connections, a "control connection" and a "data connection". The control connection handles passing of of commands from client to server and return status messages and the data connection is used separately to transfer the data. It sounds like this is the kind of system you need to set up.

The main thing you want to do that's different is to be able to seek to and transfer data from arbitrary offsets in your file which can be easily accomplished via custom commands. Depending on your setup, you may be able to grab existing open source implementations of FTP clients and servers and just add your custom commands.

Comment: You've grasped what it is that I'd like this protocol to achieve... It still surprises me that I can't find a 'standard' that directly addresses this.  I don't think modifying FTP is the right tactic... the modified protocol would not be interoperable with FTP. Adopting active-mode FTP (with 2 connections) unnecessarily introduces grief with firewall configuration.  It should be possible to send commands in one direction - and receive data in the other down a single TCP connection... though to terminate streams would require adoption of some kind of blocking-structure for streamed data.